# Incrementing a primary key (NUMBER) based on last value

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a very specific use case.

My table already has thousands of entries present and available in different environments(DEV, TEST etc.)

I have recently started out making use of JPA Annotations @Entity, @Table, @Id, @Column etc. Is there any functionality available in @GeneratedValue(strategy=?) to allow insertion based on checking from the last value of the primary key?

I know there is an `initialValue` attribute. But, since the table is present in different environments, the primary key has different last values. As a result, I cannot hard code it.

I am trying to avoid making a special DB call to fetch the TABLE.next_val entry before actually inserting a value.

Reason for asking: The way hibernate-jpa is working is it is trying to insert from id:0. I cannot afford to delete all entries just because I want to add hibernate-jpa persistence feature to the code.

Please let me know of an approach to solve this.

Sample code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DUMMY")
public class Dummy {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="primary_key_dummy")
    private Integer pk;
}
```

Comment: does that primary key generated by sequence ?

Comment: Not a sequence.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if it was a sequence, what might be the solution?

Comment: you can use the sequence as show in here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-strategies-when-set-primary-key#3-generationtypesequence

Comment: This would not be a very performant option, and will certainly lead to problems with concurrency (two processes trying to insert at the same time will use the same value). What I've seen done instead is to set the initial value based on what is already there - when you create the sequence, use a higher initial value to account for existing data. If you are using JPA to execute DDL, just look at the scripts generated and either modify it, or take the sequence creation and control it in your own script; JPA provide create, drop and load script source options you can use to customize the tables

Comment: Ie use "SELECT setval('<yourSequence>', (Select max(id) from <YourTable>));" in the add on script which should run after the sequence is created. Check how your database handles no rows being in the Table- Postgres passed in undefined and just left the initial value  in the sequence which is desirable, but I do know how it might be on other DBs

Answer (score 0):

There is a generation type based on auto-increment. Should work fine with different databases.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long pk;
```

(Disclaimer: please check it first on DEV before going live)

Comment: Does it not start with 0 or 1? My table already has entries and it will throw UNIQUENESS violation error

Comment: Should be fine. The database will handle it for you. Based on the current value of the id. Basically using MAX(ID).